# Replace part of a string based on text in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

5:00AM      5:13AM
6:10AM      6:26AM
6:40AM      6:56AM
7:25AM      7:41AM
8:15AM      8:28AM
9:10AM      9:24AM
10:10AM     10:23AM
11:10AM     11:26AM
12:02PM     12:15PM
12:50PM     1:06PM

I am trying to create a macro where I need to replace the word AM or PM in the current cell with just the time without AM and PM if the above cell has AM or PM

For example the times in first row remains the same, the rows from 2nd row just shows times like 6:10 and 6:26 because the above cell has AM. Similarly for the PM row as well. The first row containing PM remains same but the later rows just shows numbers.

My current code is this and it doesn't seem to be working.. my excel file just crashes and have to restart EXCEL
[Required end table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtoAl.png)

```
'Remove additional AM and PM    
Dim i as Long, j as Long
Dim celltxt as String

    For i= 2 To 200
        j=3
        Do While j<50
            celltxt = Cells(i-1,j).Text
            If InStr( 1, celltext,("AM" Or "PM")) Then
            Cells(i,j).Replace What:="AM" Or "PM", Replacement:=" ", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
            Else
            End If
        Loop
    Next i
    End Sub
```

Comment: If the cell is formatted as a time (hence not a string), then you will need to use a custom format to suit your needs. Select your range, right click > Format Cells > Custom. Then type this: `h:mm`.

Comment: Are your values true time or text-that-looks-like-time? Are the cells right-aligned or left-aligned? Did you manually change the cell alignment?

Comment: Currently the cells are formatted as General and no changes to alignment have been made

Comment: My question would be why are you trying to remove AM or PM from the cell? is it for aesthetic reasons or is it because you are trying to reference the value from the cell and its causing you problems? If it's the later, there are better options available rather then trying to remove part of the string

Comment: @PranjalDixit THAT ISN'T WHAT I ASKED!!!!!!!

Comment: Your request makes no sense at all and will result in useless 'pictures' of data (i.e. text-that-looks-like-time-values). You cannot display **1:06PM** without the **PM** as real time; it will be **13:06**. The only way to create what you are asking is to make all of your values text-that-looks-like-time-values and that makes them useless for any calculation; for all intents and purposes just pictures of data instead of real, calculable data. I decline to instruct you on creating useless data tables. Good luck with your project.

Comment: @Zac it is actually for aesthetic reasons

Comment: @Jeeped I am creating a Timetable and aesthetics is a big part of it and I dont need it for colculations. I understand your concern. Thanks anyways

Comment: You still fail to describe if you have text strings or date values in your data. Without this information we cannot help you.

Comment: @FunThomas everything is text strings

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try this code:

```
'Remove additional AM and PM    
Dim i as Long, j as Long
Dim celltxt as String

    For i= 2 To 200
        For j = 3 To 49
            celltxt = Cells(i-1,j).Text
            If InStr( 1, celltext,("AM" Or "PM")) Then
            Cells(i,j).Replace What:="AM" Or "PM", Replacement:=" ", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True
            Else
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

1) Your code crashed as you don't increase the counter (`j`) of your inner loop, so the code is trapped in an endless loop (really easy to figure out when you use the debugger)

2) I think the replace doesn't accept the `or`-Clause. Instead, you have to issue 2 separate replace statements.

3) There is no reason to loop over all the data. You can replace all strings at once (maybe you have to adapt the adress of the range):

```
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("C1:AW200")
r.Replace What:="AM", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
r.Replace What:="PM", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False
```

4) Maybe a much better solution is to create real dates out of your strings and format them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out

```
'Remove additional AM and PM
    For m = 100 To 2 Step -1
        For n = 3 To 30
                celltxt = Cells(m - 1, n).Text
                    If celltxt Like "*AM*" Then
                        Cells(m, n).Replace What:="AM", Replacement:=" "
                    Else
                    End If
        Next n
    Next m
    For m = 100 To 2 Step -1
        For n = 3 To 30
                celltxt = Cells(m - 1, n).Text
                    If celltxt Like "*PM*" Then
                        Cells(m, n).Replace What:="PM", Replacement:=" "
                    Else
                    End If
        Next n
    Next m
    For m = 100 To 2 Step -1
        For n = 3 To 30
                celltxt = Cells(m - 1, n).Text
                    If celltxt Like "*-*" Then
                        Cells(m, n).Replace What:="PM", Replacement:=" "
                    Else
                    End If
        Next n
    Next m
    For m = 100 To 2 Step -1
        For n = 3 To 30
                celltxt = Cells(m - 1, n).Text
                    If celltxt Like "*-*" Then
                        Cells(m, n).Replace What:="AM", Replacement:=" "
                    Else
                    End If
        Next n
    Next m
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you ***a)*** Loop backwards? ***b)*** use 4 loops instead of one  ***c)***  assign the content of the cells to a string variable (`.Replace` will work anyhow) ***d)*** check for `*-*` at all ***e)*** have empty `else`-statements in the code ***f)*** loop at all over your cells rather than replace everything at once like I suggested in my answer?

Comment: If i use replace for the whole range, even the first rows where AM and PMs occur also get replaced.. and i have two set of tables in the same sheet with a few cells containing "-".